# Find uptime of server using ssh in php

Tags: php, ssh

I want to find the load average of the server to which am connected full time, I used the following code, but I get error on displaying the up time. please some one help me fix this...

Here is the code

```
<?php
$ip = '192.168.71.56';
$user = 'viju';
$pass = 'viju';
$connection = ssh2_connect($ip);
if($connection)
{   
 echo "connection successful";  
}
else
{
 echo "connection failed";
}
if(!(ssh2_auth_password($connection,$user,$pass)))
{
 echo "Authentication Failed";  
}
else
{
echo "Authentication Successful";
$shell = ssh2_shell($connection,"uptime");   
if($shell)
{
 $loadAvgString=explode('average:',$shell);   //line 26
 print_r($loadAvgString);
 $loadAvgInAnArray=explode(',',$loadAvgString);
 print_r($loadAvgInAnArray);
}
else
{ 
 echo "No data fetched";
}
}
?>
```

I get the following output with Warning

connection successful Authentication Successful
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in /var/www/extra/dis.php on line 26 Array ( [0] => )

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for explode must be a string joined using the string delimiter.just print that $shell variable and check whether it holds a string or not

Comment: printing $shell variable displays "Resource id #3". It doesn't display any string.. what can I do to get up time?

Comment: I think your ssh2_shell($connection,"uptime"); function return query result.If you are using mysql you can use mysql_fetch_array to fetch the data.if not check what exactly that fuction is returning.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if $shell contains something rather than whether or not it is true

```
if (!empty($shell)) {
    ...
}
```

even better

```
if (strstr($shell, "average:")) {
    ...
}
```